# How can I send an email of who is logged off?

Tags: powershell

I want to be able to send an email of who was logged off of each computer. How can I accomplish this?

$username = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input Username'

## Create a fresh variable to collect the results. You can use this to output as desired

$SessionList = "ACTIVE SERVER SESSIONS REPORT - " + $today + "`n`n"

## Query Active Directory for computers running a Server operating system

Get-Content -Path '\server\share$\1 - Admin Tools\Power Shell Scripts\Log Users Off Servers\Serverlist.csv' | select -Skip 1 | Set-Content "\data01\it$\1 - Admin Tools\Power Shell Scripts\Log Users Off Servers\servers.csv"

$Servers = Get-Content -Path '\server\share$\1 - Admin Tools\Power Shell Scripts\Log Users Off Servers\Servers.csv'

## Loop through the list to query each server for login sessions

ForEach ($Server in $Servers) {

```
$list = $Server -replace '"', "" 

# When running interactively, uncomment the Write-Host line below to show which server is being queried 
$message = "Querying" +" "+ $list 


$message

# Run the qwinsta.exe and parse the output 
$queryResults = (qwinsta $username /server:$Server | foreach { (($_.trim() -replace "\s+",","))} | ConvertFrom-Csv)

# Pull the session information from each instance 
ForEach ($queryResult in $queryResults){ 
    $RDPUser = $queryResult.USERNAME 
    $sessionType = $queryResult.ID
    if ($sessionType -eq "Disc"){$sessionType = $RDPUser} else { $sessionType = $queryResult.ID}

    Write-Host "Logging $username off of $list with Session# $sessionType"

     logoff $sessionType /server:$Server

      }
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you already have the username. So if you have the [AD module](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/ashleymcglone/2016/02/26/install-the-active-directory-powershell-module-on-windows-10/) installed you can use the

```
$Mail = (Get-ADUser $username -properties Mail).mail
```

to get the email id of the user. Then you can use the

```
Send-MailMessage -to $mail -From <random mail id for eg noreplyAD@mail.com> -Body "Your $username has been logged off of $server" -Subject "Logoff notification" -SmtpServer <yourcompany's smtpserver>
```

to send a notification to the user

Comment: If you dont have the AD module installed on the machine you are running this on, you can always `invoke-command` into a machine with the module and get the email. Either way, you need a way to get the mail ID.